# Vim in Alacritty and inside tmux cannot display italic text

Tags: vimrc, filetype-markdown

I am trying to have a better visualization while editing Markdown file in vim, I try to visualize the italic and bold text. However, I found the bold italic text work, while the italic itself doesn't work. It happens outside and insde tmux. I have try use another font, while the italic text itself still not display properly. I don't why the bold italic text can work.

Version of OS, Vim and Terminal emulator:

```
MacOS : 12.6
Vim : 9.0
Alacritty : 0.11.0
```

inside `alacritty.yml`:

```
font:
  normal:
    family: Menlo 
  size: 14.0
```

Inside `.vimrc`:

```
set background=dark
if !has('gui_running') && &term =~ '^\%(screen\|tmux\)'
  let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
  let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif
syntax on
set termguicolors
colorscheme onedark
```

Inside `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -ag terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:RGB"
```

The terminal emulator does support italic:

[image: Screenshot of italic test]

Screenshot of the issue in markdown file:

[image: Bold and italic text in vim]

---

Here is the lines in `~/.vim/colors/onedark.vim` that related to markdown italic highlight.
[image]

Comment: I have to agree with the answer below; the issue isn't that Vim + Alacritty + Tmux don't support italic, it's that the markdown syntax isn't applying italics correctly in `_Italic text_`.

Comment: Answers do not belong as edits to questions. Please post an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your italic text [shouldn't be blue](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim/blob/main/colors/onedark.vim#L454) to begin with, so I would investigate why this is the case.

You should probably start by identifying the actual highlight group used for `_Italic text_`.

1. Execute this command:

   ```
   :command! SS echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
   ```
2. Execute `:SS` with the cursor on `_Italic text_`.

   It should echo something like this:

   ```
   ['markdownItalic']
   ```

Report back with the actual output.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I have followed the command you provide, it echos `['mkdNonListItemBlock', 'htmlItalic']` instead of `['markdownItalic']`, the color is blue because I have use colorscheme for it, I will add this to the question also. I will also try to change the highlight group of `['mkdNonListItemBlock', 'htmlItalic']` to see if any change apply.

Answer (score 0):

I have find a solution.
Add highlight group to each items I want it in italic in the color scheme soruce file:

```
highlight foo cterm=italic
```

It seems like my color scheme cannot handle with italic text, which require me to add those lines manually. The color scheme I am using are onedark for Vim.